# Making An Object Move C#

Tags: c#, physics, monogame

I'm making a game in c# and I'm trying to make my texture move. I need some help and advice to make the texture move. This is what I've used so far.

```
public float InitialTime { get; set; }

public Vector2 InitialPosition { get; set; }

public Vector2 InitialVelocity { get; set; }

public Vector2 Position(GameTime time)
{
    float t = (float)time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds = InitialTime;
    return InitialPosition + t * InitialVelocity;
}
```

on the '`float t`' line, it comes up with the following error,

> Error CS0131  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable,
>   property or indexer

Comment: Did you mean to have two `=` signs on that line?

Comment: yeah  but I'm still unsure why I have an error. I've watched videos about this and what the end of all this, my .png image was meant to go down diagonally.

Comment: You're trying to change one of the values `GameTime` holds, which you probably shouldn't do. The reason for the error is because of the `float` cast. You are effectively trying to set `TotalSeconds` to `InitialTime` and then set `t`. Why?

Comment: The problem is in the second half of the assignment then. in `(float)time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds = InitialTime;` you are casting the left side which makes the program interpret the left side as a statement. This makes the syntax for the assignment operator wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't you be subtracting InitialTime from TotalGameTime (so replacing the second '=' by a '-')?

Comment: Is your `=` supposed to be subtraction `-` instead? You want: `float t = (float)time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds - InitialTime;`, where "initial time" I'm assuming is the "Time this object obtained its current velocity". Otherwise your code doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: oh thanks so much it was ment to be a subraction. the error is now gone. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of this:

```
float t = (float)time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds = InitialTime;
```

Both sides of an assignment operation need to have valid syntax. If you were to isolate the second assignment, it would look like this:

```
(float)time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds = InitialTime;
```

Which is not only invalid syntax, but it also makes little sense.

I imagine that the reason you are doing the cast is because `TotalSeconds` and `InitialTime` are doubles and you need to cast them to a float. There are two ways to accomplish this.

You can either split up the assignment onto two different lines:

```
time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds = InitialTime;
float t = (float)time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

Or, if you insist on doing this on a single line, use parentheses to group your operations:

```
float t = (float)(time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds = InitialTime);
```

EDIT:

Then again, I've been assuming that the double assignment was intentional. What you may have meant to do was to subtract `InitialTime` from your `TotalTime` to get the current time stamp. In that case, it's just a simple fix of a typo:

```
float t = (float)(time.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds - InitialTime);
```

*(Note that if `TotalSeconds` and `InitialTime` are doubles, you will need to use parentheses to cast the operation to a float, as I have done.)*

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you given :)